# Why LESS css does not work on localhost

Tags: html, css, localhost, less

According to this [tutorial](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/09/an-introduction-to-less-and-comparison-to-sass/) my less code should work but it doesn't.

Can you please help me to get my less css to work.

Right now it does not working - Page loads with no applied styles. What am I doing wrong?

The error is:

FileError: 'localhost:1/styles.less' wasn't found (404) in styles.less

But it is there in the root?

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less">
    <script src="_/script/less-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="header">test</div>

    <h2>test h2</h2>

</body>

</html>
```

styles.less

**LESS**

```
@color: red;

#header {
    color: @color;
}
h2 {
    color: @color;
}
```

Comment: Look at chrome developer tools and make sure the less/js are actually loaded

Comment: What happens when you hit the styles.less URL? Does it render css from the less?

Comment: -1, please modify this question so it'll be useful for future wandering people with similar issues. As it is, your question is too local (or at least your description is too generically worded).

Comment: I thought this was a question answer site

Comment: ftom2 -  yes its loaded - is it possible to load a test in js fiddle?

Comment: [**Works as expected in plunker.**](http://plnkr.co/edit/wyeHdmjkyLQNOFX2KTwD?p=preview)

Comment: thanks I never knew about that to test.  could it be an issue in fire fox on local host?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for your help everyone - turns out the answer is that my localhost did not serve the mime type .less

Comment: To make your localhost serve the mime type, change the file: apache/conf/mime.types. Find the line with the css type, and add less, like this: 
text/css css less

Answer (score 11):

If you are using IIS you  have to add a ".less" extension to MIME type within IIS manager. when you add a new MIMI, enter ".less" as the extension and "text/css" as the MIME type.

Answer (score 11):

Assuming the website is hosted over iis express, Open the file

C:\Users\\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config

and search for the tag
`<staticContent lockAttributes="isDocFooterFileName">`

and add the .less MIME as below

`<mimeMap fileExtension=".latex" mimeType="application/x-latex" />`

**`<mimeMap fileExtension=".less" mimeType="text/css" />`**

`<mimeMap fileExtension=".lit" mimeType="application/x-ms-reader" />`

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue too.

None of the above fixes worked, however I did manage to fix it when I checked the folder access that the less.css file was stored in.

Adding the IUSR user to have read rights to the folder allowed the file to be distributed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your source location of your file is not correct.

```
<script src="_/script/less-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have never seen that "_" could be used for navigation. Actually, if the script folder is in the same directory as the html page, then

```
<script src="script/less-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

should be enough to have a working js file on your page.

Comment: I put my script in  a folder called "_" that has everything in it. I saw it in a example the other day and thought Id try it out. thanks for the help but the source is correct.

Comment: Ah by this way... Well, each browser have a page source (fe Ctrl + U at Firefox). There, you can click on the links, so the script too. Please click on it and see if it displays the content of your script file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using IIS 7.5 but this can be the same for other IIS versions:

The mime type for less must be added to IIS. But in my case, I have to add it to "Default Web Site" using IIS Manager, NOT to my application, to be able to load less file from browser.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I already had the mimeType for .less on ISS, so I checked the Web.config file of my web and removed the following line because it was causing a duplication:

```
<mimeMap fileExtension=".less" mimeType="text/css" />
```